# Required to implement Autolayout Constraint and SizeClasses?

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I have an iPhone app which should support for iOS 7 to iOS 9(Enhancement) and all the screen sizes as well. Storyboards are enabled Use AutoLayout and Use Size Classes properties. I am not much familiar with using auto layout.

Do I need to add constraints for views to support all the screen sizes?  Is there any other ways to achieve that? Launch Images and Icons are enough for all the screen resolutions? will make any problem when iTunes submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to it is recommended to run application on all iphone as well as ipad using a single design , use these tutorials it would help

1.) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

2.) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-adaptive-design--cms-22888

Comment: Thank you. It is going to run on iPhone not iPad. I did not add any constraints in my storyboard and designed it in 4 Inches, but it is adapting to all the screen sizes automatically. I just added Launch images for all the sizes. How is it working? Is there any reason to recommend it?

Comment: Have to try it on all iphones like 4,4s,5,5s,6,6Plus?

Comment: Sorry Launch Images was not update properly. It is not working as expected. I am redesigning view to Autolayout.